# Why axes aren't visible here

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f1,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(num=1,nrows=2, ncols=1)
f2,(ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(num=2,nrows=2, ncols=1)

plt.close(2)
plt.close(1)

plt.figure(2)
plt.show()
```

Figure 2 is shown, but there are no axes on figure, why is that?
And how to make it to show axes while figure 1 is closed and vice versa?

Comment: There are no axes on it because you closed it, which destroys the figure, and then re-created it with `plt.figure(2)`

Comment: If you have a specific condition where you have to show figure 1 and close figure 2 or vice versa depending on some condition; then you can add `if` condition to specify which one to close nad which to open.

Comment: @YassineMajdoub what i want to do is a loop in which i want to decide which figure i want to see at the moment, so at some point in time i want 'f1' to be closed and 'f2' to be visible, and then i want 'f2' to be closed and 'f1' to be visible, and then again 'f1' to be closed and 'f2' to be visible. But if I close 'f1' then i cant 'unclose' it. How do i do this?

Comment: @JodyKlymak So closing figure means destrying it and it's axes? So how can I create app in which i create 2 figures but at some point in time i want to show only 1 of them? I mean like in a loop, i want to be able to chose which one i want to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i created an input variable where the user can choose the figure he wants to see (in your case this variable can be the output of some calculation or something).

`glob = int(input('Enter figure number'))`

Then I used the same plotting code you provided (I added the lists of values to make sure the thing actually works) to define the figures:

```
f1,(ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(num=1,nrows=2, ncols=1)
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,np.exp(x))

f2,(ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(num=2,nrows=2, ncols=1)
ax3.plot(x,y)
ax4.plot(x,np.sqrt(x))
```

Then I used a condition on the user entry to select the figure to plot by closing the other one:

```
if glob==1:
    plt.close(2)
elif glob==2:
    plt.close(1)
else:
    print('Figure non defined')
```

**Please note** that this solution works only once and you will have to run the program each time you want to chose a figure.
To solve this issue, here is another alternative:

```
i=0
while i<4:
    glob = int(input('Enter figure number'))
    if glob==1:
        f1,(ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(num=1,nrows=2, ncols=1)
        ax1.plot(x,y)
        ax2.plot(x,np.exp(x))
        plt.show()
    elif glob==2:
        f2,(ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(num=2,nrows=2, ncols=1)
        ax3.plot(x,y)
        ax4.plot(x,np.sqrt(x))
        plt.show()
    else:
        print('Figure non defined')
    i+=1
```

Practically, you need to define the figures inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When I got rid of `plt.close()`, it plotted as expected:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f1,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(num=1,nrows=2, ncols=1)
f2,(ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(num=2,nrows=2, ncols=1)

plt.show()
```

I've used matplotlib a lot, and have never had a reason to use, nor have ever even seen `plt.close`. My guess is that it's unnecessary unless you have a specific use case.

Comment: What i want to do is a app with loop, and in that loop i want to chose one of these 2 figures and then show the one i have chosen. So what im doing is closing one of them and showing the other

Comment: @BIGoperaFAN, it seems like that's a fundamentally different question. You might want to search questions on stack overflow, like "how to use matplotlib in a loop", or, if you want these plots to be animated, you might want to look up "how to animate plot matplotlib"